# Beamer slides look blurry at lower resolutions

Tags: fonts, pdftex, beamer

I prepare slides using Beamer and PDFLaTeX. The command I use to run PDFLaTeX is the default AUCTeX command:

```
pdflatex  -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" <INPUT_FILE>
```

The slides look fine on my screen at my default resolution (1360x768), but if I have to step down the resolution (e.g., to 640x480) when I connect to a projector, they look aliased and blurry. Probably this has something to do with the kinds of fonts that are being used, but I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that 640 x 480 is really the native resolution of your projector? I'd assume that if you use such a low resolution, your projector has to scale up the image, and *everything* will look blurry. A typical projector today has a native resolution of something like 1024 x 768; perhaps you should try that first?

Comment: I honestly can't say what resolution I was at. I was in a talk, using borrowed equipment, and I just blustered through with a lousy configuration. It may have been the laptop (also borrowed) that balked and not the projector.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the fonts you're using. If you use the standard Computer Modern fonts but T1 font encoding, it may already help to install the [cm-super](http://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super) package and recompile. There's no change in your tex file needed. cm-super contains Computer Modern fonts with T1 support.

Or switch to another T1 supporting font like lmodern, which is very similar to the standard font. `\usepackage{lmodern}` could be sufficient.